# SSH through shadowsocks?

Tags: ssh, shadowsocks

How could I route my SSH traffic through shadowsocks?

I am connecting from behind the Great Fire Wall to a server using shadowsocks. I would like to make outgoing SSH connections but I am concerned that SSH traffic could be identified and so result in my connection getting shutdown. Hence, I would like to be able to route the SSH traffic through the SOCKS5 proxy that I already have working.

Where do I start to achieve this? I assume I need to create a virtual network adaptor that can present a range of ports from which the output is routed over the SOCKS5 proxy somehow?

Answer (score 7):

If your configuration of shadowsocks is:

- local address : 127.0.0.1
- local port : 1080
- server ip 42.42.42.42

change for your own configuration

```
sudo apt install connect-proxy
```

Edit your ~/.ssh/config

```
# Outside of the firewall, with HTTPS proxy
Host 42.42.42.42
  ProxyCommand connect -H 127.0.0.1:1080 %h 22
## Inside the firewall (do not use proxy)
Host *
  ProxyCommand connect %h %p
```

**Now you can try:**

```
ssh username@ipserver
```

check ip connection

```
netstat -tn 2>/dev/null
```

normally you can see something like that

```
Connexions Internet actives (sans serveurs)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat       
tcp        0     68 69.69.69.69:22        42.42.42.42:42800      ESTABLISHED
```

**More skills**

Add this script to your `~/.bash_profile.`

**SOCKS5**

```
export http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
export https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
```

**OR**

**HTTP(S)**

```
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1080
export https_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:1080
```

if you want setup webconnection for your Web browser

Gui way (gnome)

1. setting
2. network
3. proxy server
4. enter your configuration
5. don't forget to disable proxy for localhost

[image]

or just add all proxy redirection to your env

env | grep -i proxy

must be return

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:1080/
FTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:1080/
ALL_PROXY=socks://127.0.0.1:1080/
NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1,localhost
HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:1080/
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1080/
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1080/
no_proxy=127.0.0.1,localhost
all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:1080/
ftp_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1080/
```

if you just want config curl through shadowsocks

```
export socks5=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
```

and

```
curl api.ipify.org
```

**For Git**

```
git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'
git config --global https.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'
```

Comment: I'd like to add a note - if you are doing SSH for a user@my-server ( like when connecting to EC2 in the default way) then replace the server IP with the part at my-server

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way, use a match directive in your ssh config file:

```
Match Exec "nc -z 127.0.0.1 1086"
     ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:1086 %h %p
```

This directive will execute every time you ssh (Matches everything).  First it tries to connect to your shadowsocks proxy using `nc`: the -z option just means to check the port with no IO.  My ssocks proxy runs on port 1086.  If it's running, then set a ProxyCommand, if it doesn't, don't, and connect normally, without a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

`tsocks` works for me on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt install tsocks
```

Configure it in `/etc/tsocks.conf`:

```
# Local networks accessible without socks server
local = 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0
# Socks server address
server = 127.0.0.1
# Server type SOCKS5
server_type = 5
# Server port
server_port = 1080
```

Then you can go by:

```
tsocks ssh USER@SERVER
```

Had to also configure SSH timeout in SERVER's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# 10 minutes
ClientAliveInterval 10m
# Max number of client alive messages without response
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

This would automatically disconnect a client after 30 minutes. (See `man sshd_config` for details about the meaning of these two parameters.)